# override the module-list.phtml by theme list.phtml

Tags: magento-1.9, module, overrides, product-list

please visit [link1](http://beta.stylebaby.com/cases-cover.html) , in listing page 4 images are displaying.

[image]

we needed "pre-order" feature [ user can buy out-of-stock Products ]

so we wrote custom module , after listing page looks like [link2](http://sb1.collagekingapp.com/apple.html)

[image]

module-list.phtml is overriding theme-list.phtml

we want to re-override  module-list.phtml by the theme list.phtml

**i can delete module-list.phtml , but after that list.phtml will not visible**

**Edit**

there is some problem with links when visit 1st time. please copy below url in browser tabs urls :

http://sb1.collagekingapp.com/apple.html

Comment: when visit your link it shows 404 for first time. second time same link shows page properly. can you please explain your question more in details.

Comment: what is the value you set system->configuration->catalog->catalog->frontend->Products per Page on Grid Default Value

Comment: @Kothari we set "4" as value.

Comment: In your phtml change this <?php $_columnCount = $this->getColumnCount(); ?> into <?php $_columnCount = 4; ?>

Comment: @Kothari it didt worked for me

Comment: it working i check ur link adjust ur css .products-grid > li {
    margin-right: 3.7037%;
    width: 21.864%;
}.products-grid > li {
    margin-right: 3.7037%;
    width: 21.864%;
}

Comment: add !important or find css and the change

Comment: @Kothari it didt worked for me, may i am doing some thing wrong, i will check & let you know.

Comment: check your inspect elment now it showing 4 li so you will do some css for allignment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your `.phtml` try this

In your phtml change this 
`<?php $_columnCount = $this->getColumnCount(); ?>` into `<?php $_columnCount = 4; ?>`

also adjust your css based on width

Comment: let me check and inform you.